# How to get RAM details of ESP32 using NodeMCU Lua

Tags: lua, esp8266, esp32, nodemcu

What is the best way to debug ESP32 with NodeMCU firmware memory related issues, I need to know flash info, RAM size and memory related info. I tried

```
node.heap()
node.info()
```

but those are not working for me. My main concern is to debug **Lua out of memory error** for that I need those information.

Comment: is this what your looking for `node.egc.meminfo()`?https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/release/modules/node/#nodeegcmeminfo

Comment: Hi but I'm using dev-esp32 firmware so I can't use those API

Comment: "those are not working for me" isn't a particularly helpful statement. _What_ is not working or _why_ are then not working for you?